# Shiny app plot related question -reactive

Tags: r, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I am having two columns in my data frame, one is "all_pass" which contains numeric values and other is "st_name" which contains string values name of states

The requirement of the plot is , when user give input of the state it will show the plot of that particular state which contains all_pass numbers

Following is the code in which I am trying to plot, where the user will input the name of the state and as per the input of the state name, the graph will plot as per the all_pass as per the related pass scores to that particular state. Kindly help in the following code, will be of great help.

Code is as mentioned below :

```
library(ggplot2)

library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

library(shiny)



ui <- basicPage(
  h1("Total bills passed by state delegation , 110th Congress"),
  selectizeInput(inputId = "bins",label = "Choose State",
    choices = list("AK","AL","AR","AS","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","FL","GA","GU","HI","IA","ID","IL","IN","KS","KY","LA","MA","MD","ME","MI","MN","MO","MS","MT","NC","NE","ND","NH","NJ","NM","NV","NY","OH","OK","OR","PA","PR","RI","SC","SD","TN","TX","UT","VA")  ,multiple = TRUE ,plotOutput("plot"))
  
  )
  

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    require(input$bins)
    df <- df7 %>% filter(st_name %in% input$bins)
  })
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(df(), aes(y= all_pass,x=st_name ))+geom_bar(stat = "sum")
         })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. in the UI definition you have `plotOutput("plot")` as an argument to `selectizeInput()` instead of `basicPage()`. Reformatting your code (Ctrl+Shift+A) would have made that more visible.
2. You can simplify the server code, as the `renderPlot()` already creates a reactive dependence on `input$bins`.
3. You can use the object `datasets::state.abb` to get a vector of US state abbreviations. This is loaded automatically in every R session.

Please see some working code below. I am using some mock data for `df` as you did not provide any data in your question.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

ui <- basicPage(
  h1("Total bills passed by state delegation, 110th Congress"),
  selectizeInput(inputId = "bins",
                 label = "Choose State",
                 choices = state.abb,
                 multiple = TRUE),
  plotOutput("plot")
  
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  df <- 
    tibble(all_pass = sample(1:500, 350),
           st_name = rep(state.abb, 7))

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$bins)
    df |> 
      filter(st_name %in% input$bins) |> 
      ggplot(aes(y = all_pass,x=st_name )) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "sum")
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That was really great.... I am really thankful to you... thanks a lot for your help.. God bless you.....

Comment: One more question here, while I am rendering this in individual code chunk in R Markdown file, it is giving perfect ouput, however, when I run in flex dashboard shiny  it the ouput is showing only on half of the page, I have tried adjusting column width as well, but it is not working, can you help on this as well..

Comment: You should as a new question for the new issue.